# SQL to PDO For Transferring Table Contents To Another Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to change a email confirmation function written in sql to PDO. This is the tutorial for your further reference: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/24.html.

This particular section will move the user's information from the temporary table to the permanent table after they click on the verification link sent to their email.

The problem I am having is under this header within that tutorial: **STEP4: confirmation.php**

My code is similar to that, but I added a few prepared statements as I am trying to prevent SQL injection.

To be clear: I am looking for direction on what else I need to do to switch this from sql to PDO and prevent any sql injection. Examples when providing an answer are crucial as I am a visual learner. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

include('config.php');

//Test DB connection
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$Host;db=$svrDb", Username, $Password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

// Passkey that got from link
$passkey=$_GET['passkey'];

$sql1= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM temp_members_db WHERE confirm_code ='$passkey'");
$sql_conf1->execute() or die ('Error updating database: '.mysql_error());
$result1=$sql1->fetchall();

// If successfully queried
if($result1){

// Count how many row has this passkey
$count=mysql_num_rows($result1);

// if found this passkey in our database, retrieve data from table "temp_members_db"
if($count==1){

$name=$rows['name'];
$email=$rows['email'];
$password=$rows['password'];
$country=$rows['country'];

// Insert data that retrieves from "temp_members_db" into table "registered_members"
$sql2="INSERT INTO registered_members(name, email, password, country)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$password', '$country')";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
}

// if not found passkey, display message "Wrong Confirmation code"
else {
echo "Wrong Confirmation code";
}

// if successfully moved data from table"temp_members_db" to table "registered_members" displays message "Your account has been activated" and don't forget to delete confirmation code from table "temp_members_db"
if($result2){

echo "Your account has been activated";

// Delete information of this user from table "temp_members_db" that has this passkey
$sql3="DELETE FROM temp_members_db WHERE confirm_code = '$passkey'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);

}

}
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem and where are the prepared statements you are talking about? I see one but as you are injecting your variables in the query directly, a prepared statement is not of much use. You should bind your variables.

Comment: @jeroen are not these prepared statments?

`$sql1= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM temp_members_db WHERE confirm_code ='$passkey'");
$sql_conf1->execute() or die ('Error updating database: '.mysql_error());
$result1=$sql1->fetchall();`

How can I switch this section of the code to be PDO?

`$name=$rows['name'];
$email=$rows['email'];
$password=$rows['password'];
$country=$rows['country'];`

Also, what is not PDO worthy here?

Comment: Check the php manual on `prepare()`. You'll notice they use placeholders to bind the variables. When you inject them like you do, you still have an sql injection problem. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: I.e. `$sql2="INSERT INTO registered_members(name, email, password, country)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$password', '$country')";` that's concatenation of a sql statement. it should be something like ``$sql2="INSERT INTO registered_members(name, email, password, country)VALUES(:name, :email, :hashedpassword, :country)";`. Then prepare a statement and execute it with binding of the inputs to the named parameters. And it's no good idea to store cleartext passwords too.

Comment: Thanks, @VMai. Any other pointers on what I need to do to this in order to convert the sql to PDO? New programmer here and don't recognize what code is sql.

Comment: It would be a good idea to learn it. How can you query a database without knowing how you do it. Have a go at phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench or whatever client you like and write queries against databases to get a feeling what they do. You will recognize these statements mostly by the keyword `sql` as in $sql1= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM temp_members_db WHERE confirm_code =:passkey");` (I inserted a named parameter for you ...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you're on the right track but not quite....

The whole reason you use Prepared Statements is so that the database knows what to interpret as SQL, and what not to interpret as SQL. Right now, you have the following:

```
$sql1= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM temp_members_db WHERE confirm_code ='$passkey'");
$sql_conf1->execute() or die ('Error updating database: '.mysql_error());
$result1=$sql1->fetchall();
```

To take full advantage of PDO and Prepared Statements you should change it to something like this:

```
$sql1= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM temp_members_db WHERE confirm_code = ?");
try{
     $sql1->execute(array($passkey));
}catch(PDOException $e){
     print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
     die();
}
$result1=$sql1->fetchall();
```

There are a couple reasons for this. In your code, you send the variable `$passkey` along with your prepare statement, so in essence the prepare operation is useless because `$passkey` has not been sanitized. Notice in my code I replaced it with a `?`. This tells the database:

*"Hey, I'm going to be executing a SELECT statement and I'm going to replace the `?` with a value from one of my variables, so don't interpret that as SQL!"*

Here is a great resource for PDO:

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers